# What is the best way to create text input Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I Created a simple text field component using react-redux.

This is a dumb component, so it receive a call back function to dispatch the change.

So on each change it changes its local state and on Blur it calls the call back function.

I think i'm doing too much for such a simple task it look like an overkill, is there better/shorter way to implement it?

```
 export default class CreativeName extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            creativeName: props.creativeName
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            creativeName: nextProps.creativeName
        });
    }

    onBlur() {
        this.props.updateDraft('creativeName', this.state.creativeName);
    }

    onChange(e) {`enter code here`
        this.setState({creativeName: e.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Row>
                <Col lg={12} className="row-margin">
                    <ControlLabel>*Name</ControlLabel>
                    <div className="campaign-name">
                        <FormControl value={this.state.creativeName} type="text" onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)}
                                     onBlur={(e) => this.onBlur(e)} className="campaign-name-text-field" />
                    </div>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `onBlur` to capture the data. No need to use `onChange` and state here. What do you think?

Comment: I need the value of the text filed to update on each change, on other hand i don't want to render whole page each time, that's why i separate events

Comment: I see, then i suggest solution by @biofractal using `react-redux` `connect`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I really recommend that use [redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form). `redux-form` store input values in global state. By `redux-from` you can have very usable input tags of react components.

For example:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

export default class FormInputTextBox extends Component {
  static PropTypes = {
    field: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    placeholder: PropTypes.string,
    disabled: PropTypes.bool
  }
  render() {
    const {field, placeholder, disabled} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          {...field}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          disabled={disabled}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the `connect` feature supplied by the `react-redux` package. I would recast your code so it looked something like this (syntax is ES6):

**container.js**

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {presenter} from './presenter'
import {actions} from '../../loader'

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) =>({
    creativeName: props.creativeName
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>({
    updateDraft : (creativeName) => dispatch(actions.updateDraft('creativeName', creativeName))
})

const container = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(presenter)

export {
    container
}
```

The `actions` above is just a file containing standard redux action creators.

**presenter.js**

```
function presenter ({creativeName}, updateDraft) {

    const onBlur=e=>updateDraft(e.target.value)

    return (
        <Row>
            <Col lg={12} className="row-margin">
                <ControlLabel>*Name</ControlLabel>
                <div className="campaign-name">
                    <FormControl value={creativeName} type="text" onBlur={e=>onBlur(e)} className="campaign-name-text-field" />
                </div>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    )
}

export {
    presenter
}
```

In truth I would not be using any local state at all and instead would use a `selector` (see [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect)) to pull the components local state out of global state, a bit like this:

**presenter.js - mapStateToProps**

```
import {actions, services} from '../../loader'

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>({
    state: services.CreativeName.selector.getAll(state)
})
```

Its certainly a *different* way of doing things, I prefer it, but I a not sure it is any simpler.